# ant build file primitives

Tags: java, ant, primitive

What are ant primitives?

In my **build.xml** I am using a statements like:

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
<fileset dir="${src.test.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
```

how does ant know that "src.test.dir" is same as ./test-java?

Where can I find the list of ant primitives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It knows because someone has previously defined that variable/propery manually. Search your build file and see where the `src.test.dir` property gets defined. It should be something like:

```
<!-- Source directory for tests -->
<property name="src.test.dir" value="${basedir}/test-java"/>
```

By default, ant has only a limited set of properties as described [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html)

Comment: yes...there is a property file defined like <property file="${basedir}/build.properties" />

Comment: one more question...there is an entry in build.properties file "resourcesPath=..." what does it mean?

Comment: most probably, as its name suggests, it's a directory containing some sort of resources like, images, propery files, xml files, etc, that are require by the build process and/or the application

Answer (score 0):

It's a **property**, not a **primitive**.

It's being defined in your build file, a build property file, or on the command line.

Comment: Hey thanks... yes, now I saw there is a build.properties file. one more question....there is an entry in build.properties file "resourcesPath=..." what does it mean?

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 Without any context it's impossible to say.

Comment: there are just three dots "resourcesPath=..."

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 Again, without context, impossible to say. `...` goes up a directory level.